# Too many Active Directory groups a performance issue?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

I am using Active Directory as a identity and group repository for my web application. I connect to it remotely through the LDAP SSL interface and perform operations such as creating users (who has memberships to one  or more groups), creating groups and authenticating users.

I could potentially have tens of thousands of small *groups* (maybe 50,000) for, say 100,000 user, in a flat structure. I am wondering if this is going to be a performance issue when calling Active Directory through LDAP. Active directory enforces uniqueness on username and group names. Should I be concerned that operations like creating and updating user might become too slow as the number of groups grows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As long as you have your indexes set up correctly. It's not a flat structure once it's indexed.

Comment: Thanks EJP. I have to admit that I am a total newbie when it comes to AD itself. That is, the extent of my knowledge is calling it through LDAP and maybe adding a couple of attributes to objects. So: Can you please tell me generally what I would need to do to "set up my indexes" in AD beyond just using the default config / indexing scheme? Thanks!

Comment: @pastafarian I can't actually, it was a generic comment. All LDAP servers are backed by real databases with definable indexes. How you do that in AD specifically I can't say.

Comment: You shouldn't need to tweak anything out of the box in terms of indexing for this to perform. This is a standard use case.

Comment: So what I am hearing is that large user and group creation / lookup doesn't in itself pose a performance issue when accessed through LDAP API.